# Problems Outputting PHP from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to import MySQL data into PHP through the Wordpress PHP Snippet plugin. For whatever reason I keep getting error 'mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean'.

My code is as follows:

Connection

```
[insert_php]
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "albert", "notrealpassword") or die     
(mysql_error());
```

PHP

```
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');    
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($subjectone = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{echo $subjectone['dataintable'];}
[/insert_php]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because before the last result the answer of mysql_fetch_array is array but while waits for bolean.
Also probably you know it is better to use new MySQLi functions

```
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');    
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while (is_array($subjectone = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{echo $subjectone['dataintable'];}
```

Comment: I know that in php-documentation there are many examples where while used in same way as @JasonChen used, but in same documentation you'll see that boolean conversion of array is false in same cases. So in this way you'll be able to analise returned result.